# I have a problem with the data security supeadgr challenge

Tags: security, trailhead, superbadges

I set the profile several times but still continues with the error
step 4

(Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
The Field Sales User profile does not have the correct permissions for managing List Views, creating and managing reports, or creating and managing report folders.)

[image: Fild Sales User]

[image]

Comment: [Trailhead Challenge community](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ipt8QAA#!/feedtype=POPULAR&dc=Trailhead_Challenges&criteria=BESTANSWERS) is the best resource for issues in Trailhead modules.

Answer (score 2):

For the Field Sales User:

Uncheck everything in the "Administrative Permissions" and "General User Permissions" sections other than the following:
API Enabled,
Chatter Internal User,
Create and Customize Dashboards,
Create and Customize List Views,
Create and Customize Reports,
Edit My Dashboards,
Edit My Reports,
Run Reports